Create MATERIALIZED VIEW in redshift using kinesis stream
I am using below query to create metalized view in redshift ,
`CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW test_sch."new_vw" AUTO REFRESH YES AS
SELECT approximate_arrival_timestamp,
JSON_PARSE(kinesis_data) as data,
kinesis_data.dynamodb."Keys"."Id"."S" as prospectId  ,
kinesis_data.dynamodb."NewImage"."Name"."S" as prospectName,
kinesis_data.dynamodb."NewImage"."SessionId"."S" as gaSessionId
from kds_schema."test-stream-dev"
WHERE CAN_JSON_PARSE(kinesis_data);`

Error :- Navigation on column data is not allowed as its super type.
I tried using super key parsing like below
kinesis_data.dynamodb."Keys"."Id"."S" as prospectId 
But Unable to navigate SUPER key

"kinesis_data" is varchar and "data" is super, so you cannot reference the super fields by the varchar name. You need to use "data".
I also believe that you are going to need to move the JSON_PARSE() and CAN_JSON_PARSE() to a subquery or CTE. As if I remember correctly Redshift will need this level of SELECT to be able to use the fields.
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW test_sch."new_vw" AUTO REFRESH YES AS
SELECT approximate_arrival_timestamp,
  data,
  data.dynamodb."Keys"."Id"."S" as prospectId,
  data.dynamodb."NewImage"."Name"."S" as prospectName,
  data.dynamodb."NewImage"."SessionId"."S" as gaSessionId
from (
  SELECT approximate_arrival_timestamp, JSON_PARSE(kinesis_data) as data
  FROM kds_schema."test-stream-dev"
  WHERE CAN_JSON_PARSE(kinesis_data)
);


CREATE materialized VIEW test_sch."new_vw" auto refresh yes AS
SELECT data.dynamodb."Keys"."prospectId"."s"       AS prospectId ,
data.dynamodb."NewImage"."prospectName"."s" AS prospectName
FROM   (
SELECT Json_parse(kinesis_data) AS data
FROM   kds_schema."test-stream-dev"
WHERE  Can_json_parse(kinesis_data))
Error
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: improper qualified name (too many dotted names): data.dynamodb.keys.prospectid.s

Shouldn't "s" be "S"?  What have you tried?  Does the SELECT run?  Sample data? Without test case further answering would be guessing.

One of the field  urlDetails has has  input:-  "urlDetails": {"L": [  {   "type": {  "S": "Health Assessment"},"url": {  "S": "healthassessment.com"}}  },  {"M": {"type": {  "S": "Facebook"},"url": {  "S": "facebook.com"}}  },  {"M": {"type": {  "S": "Instagram"},"url": {  "S": "instagram.com"}}  }]}
I want it to be stored as     [   {     "type": "Health Assessment",     "url": "healthAssessment.com"   },   {     "type": "Facebook",     "url": "facebook.com"   },   {     "type": "Instagram",     "url": "instagram.com"   } ]

getting error
SQL Error [XX000]: ERROR: Materialized view over stream could not be created, reason: Column aliases are not supported. @Bill Weiner
